# how to change font style of tile of activity

Tags: android

I am trying to change the font style to `Cambria`, of tile on the header/action-bar of an activity in my Android application. For that I am diong something like this:

```
TextView tv = new TextView(MainActivity.this);
Typeface type = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/Cambria");
tv.setText("My App");
tv.setTypeface(type);
actionBar.setCustomView(tv);
```

But this is not working. So kindly help.

Comment: You seem to be missing a file extension. Are you sure that this should be `fonts/Cambria` and not `fonts/Cambria.ttf` or something like that? Also, have you purchased your license for this font, as [Cambria is a commercial typeface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cambria_%28typeface%29)?

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of solutions for your problem, but i would prefer you to create a custom textview and use that textview in your xml and code.

```
public class customText extends TextView {

public customText (Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    init();
}

public customText (Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    init();
}

public customText (Context context) {
    super(context);
    init();
}

public void init() {
    Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(), "fonts/Cambria.ttf");
    setTypeface(tf ,1);

}
}
```

Comment: is there any simple way to change font style in Android like in Java?